# Lambda Expression Select Min and Max at the same time

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

How do I convert this code to a Lambda expression when there are two columns to select at the same time?

**LINQ**

```
var lq=(from a in tbl
          group a by 0 into b
          select new { intYear = b.Min(p => p.intYear), tintMonth = b.Max(p => p.tintMonth) }
    ).SingleOrDefault();
```

**T-SQL**

```
SELECT MIN(intYear), MAX(tintMonth)
FROM tbl
```

**Lambda Expression**

```
tbl.Select(x => x.intYear).Min();  //Can't figure how to select if 2 columns
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're intent on returning a "row" rather than two values, you can group all the rows together as you do in the first LINQ expression:

```
tbl.GroupBy(t => 1)
   .Select(g => new { intYear = g.Min(p => p.intYear), tintMonth = g.Max(p => p.tintMonth) })
```

Note, I assume this is for LINQ-to-SQL. For plain old objects, this would most likely result in three iterations through the collection. One to do the grouping, one for the `Min()`, and one for `Max()`. For large collections, you would be be better off looping once and doing it the good-ol'-fashioned way with a single `foreach` over the collection.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. In your code, i saw this line tbl.GroupBy(t => 1), what is this purpose ? Is that a way for me to see it's actually iterate 3 times? I just want to know the method you use to check so that next time when i code I know how to troubleshoot.

Comment: It's actually exactly the same as your `group a by 0 into b`, but with 1 instead of 0 (for really no reason).

Comment: Ok, i also follow the sample code and not really sure what that for. For the iterations you mentioned above, i not get the idea why is it iterate, could you tell me how you find out that?

Comment: `GroupBy` will group the items. It's the same as a SQL `GROUP BY` clause. In this case, you're grouping by a constant which forces all rows to be grouped together into a single group. This emulates the same behavior RDBMSes do when you use an aggregate function without any specific grouping. However, for normal objects, the there is no magic AFAIK to check whether the item selected is a constant, therefore the call to `GroupBy` will iterate the collection. Then the calls to `Min` and `Max` will each iterate the resulting group, causing three loops through.